# IPv6 light on Claire App

Tags: ipv6, cloudflare, tcpdump

I am testing my new implementation and I see that with the Claire app (on Google Chrome) IPv6 does not turn on, despite my CloudFlare is set only with one AAAA record. It does not work on any website for me. Is this just because my ISP does not support IPv6 and I do not have an IPv6 address on my PC or could be due to a misconfiguration? The page does open and running `tcpdump` on the webserver shows connection is happening between IPv6 addresses only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ISP does not provide you with an IPv6 address, or if your PC is not configured with dual-stack IPv4/IPv6, or is not configured with single-stack IPv6, the Claire extension to Google Chrome will not tell you that your CloudFlare app, or any other CloudFlare app, are accessed through IPv6.